# ISO 8583 field 116 example in Java

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

I am populating ISO 8583 message and I don't know how to populate field 116. How it can be set using jpos library?

Comment: please provide enough information to know what you are talking about, a context or a reference to the field itself, the problem you are facing and so on. You can check this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Based on the packager usage, field length and type changes for field position.

for example if its postpack then its of type  `class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>`

```
ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
 isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
 isoMsg.set(116, fieldvalue);
```